# Constructor problems with class inside another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I think the question title may be impossible to get right but, I have a class (lets call it A) which has a constructor that needs a pointer to another class (called B). This would be fine but when I define a class in a third class (called C), then I get this error after putting a variable into the constructor: `error: expected identifier before ‘&’ token`, then if I remove the `&` I get: `error: ‘ClassA’ is not a type`.

For those who can't understand what I just said (I don't blame you), here is an example:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int number;
        //etc, etc...
};

class B
{
    private:
        A* ClassAPntr;

    public:
        B(A* objectPointer)
        {
            ClassAPntr = objectPointer;
        }
};

class C
{
    private:
        A ClassA;
        B ClassB(&ClassA);
};

int main()
{
    C classC;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually declare a constructor for `class C`. What you meant to do was this:

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    : b(&a)  // you have to provide the arguments to B's constructor here
    { }

private:
    A a;
    B b;    // ... not here
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Although this isn't to do with the question, why doesn't my code work (as in, why can't I declare constructors in private)? Is there a good reason, or could it be fixed in like C++20 or something?

Comment: @bboy3577 Access (i.e. `private`) isn't the issue. It's simply syntactically incorrect. C++11 introduced the ability to add a brace-or-equal-initializer for non-static data members, so you *could* do `B b{&a}` there.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, when you did `composition` by adding `A classA` `private object`  to `class C`, the compiler accept this step because A has undefined constructor  which means the compiler will make a default constructor for you and call it when make `A classA`.

The problem in `class B` because it has a non-default user defined constructor which means that compiler should force you to call it in class C through constructor initialization list or through curly braces in c++11, so it becomes your responsibility  simply because compiler can't  know which address for which `class A Object` you are going to pass for `class B` 
constructor.

So why did you get this error message : `class A is not a type` or `expected identifier before ‘&’ token`?

the answer is that compiler considered `B ClassB(&ClassA)` a declaration for a `private` function with name `ClassB` and a return value of type `B class`.

and because you never use this function in your class the compiler will never give you any error related to definition. and you will also never use this member function in other functions like main because it is private

to produce the undefined reference error you can modify `c class` to be like this:

```
class C
{

private:
  A classA;
  B classB();
  friend B func() ;
};

B func() { 
  C c;
return c.classB(); // undefined reference Error
}
```